# Dismiss completly a view controller in middle

Tags: swift, uiviewcontroller, dismiss, removefromsuperview

I've been looking for days. Here's the problem:
I have a Home view controller. When it receives a notification, it presents a NotiViewController, called `noti1`, by

```
`home.present(noti1, animated: true, completion: nil)`.
```

After 15sec, another notification comes, I get the top view controller `topVC`, present another NotiViewController, called `noti2`, by

```
`topVC.present(noti2, animated: true, completion: nil)`.
```

Each notiVC has an timer which waits for 30sec to dismiss itself. Now I have `Home` -> `noti1` -> `noti2`.

After 15sec, `noti1` runs out of time and has to be dismissed. How can I dismiss it without interupting `noti2` which is being presenting?

I tried

```
`orderVC.beginAppearanceTransition(false, animated: false)
 orderVC.willMove(toParent: nil)
 orderVC.view.removeFromSuperview()
 orderVC.removeFromParent()
 orderVC.endAppearanceTransition()`
```

These code does remove the view from screen, but it leaves a UITransitionView behind, which blocks user actions.

[image: Blocking UITrainstionView(s)]

This image is took after `noti2` is removed from superview etc, so there are 2 UITransitionViews is presenting, blocking user actions.

Any idea? Thanks a lot.

Comment: Try removing the VC in Async blocks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a way. I'm not sure if I'm correct or wrong, but here is my thought: View controller must be dismissed the way it's presented before. For example if you use `present(viewController, animated, completion)` to present, you should use `dismiss(animated, completion)` to dismiss. The problem, in my case, is if you dismiss a view controller, all child view controllers will be gone too.

The way I resolved my issue is using another way to "show" the target view controller:
    `parentVC.view.addSubview(childVC.view)
     parentVC.addChild(childVC)
     childVC.didMove(toParent: parentVC)`

After adding some view controllers, I got a tree parentVC -> child1 -> child2 -> child3... If I want to dismiss child2, the code in my question worked:
    `child2.willMove(toParent: nil)
     child2.view.removeFromSuperview()
     child2.removeFromParent()`

There is no UITransitionView blocking user actions, but it got no animation. For my this is good enough.